# Setting and accessing private var from static method in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, static

In my php file I have these vars:

```
private $db;
private $userID;
private $app;
```

And then I have this static method:

```
public static function removeAjax()
{
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

I want to change `$input =`, to use the `$app` var. Like this:

```
$input = $app->input;
```

But when the method is static, I can´t do it.

I´ve searched for solutions and tried to do it like this, but it dosen´t work:

```
private static $app;

function __construct() {    
    self::$app = JFactory::getApplication();
}

public static function removeAjax()
{
    $input = self::$app->input;
```

Comment: how about:
$app = self::$app;
$input = $app->input;

Comment: @LazarosKosmidis Thanks for the suggestion, but it dosen´t work :(